# Checking if there's a file with a particular name in a lot of directories

Tags: linux, files, directory

I'm new to Linux, but I'm wondering if this is possible:
I want to check if a directory has a file with a `.bam` filename suffix, and there are hundreds of directories to check. I don't really want to do this manually, so is it possible to check all these directories and then output *a list of the ones that don't have such a file*?

Comment: You can find all the `.bam` files with `find . -type f -name '*.bam' -print`. Then, it is easy to extract and uniquely store the directory names  into a file. Then, `find . -type d -print` will list all the directories. Use the `comm` command (`man comm`) or `diff` (`man diff`) to see the difference between "all directories with at least 1 `.bam` file" and "all directories".

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`:

```
if ()(($#)) **/*.bam(ND.Y1)); then
  print There is at least one regular file in here whose name ends in .bam
fi
```

```
directories_without_bam=(
  **/*(ND/^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*.bam(ND.Y1)'])
)

if (( $#directories_without_bam )); then
  print "Directories without bam files:"
  printf ' - %s\n' $directories_without_bam
fi
```

Note that it doesn't look at the current working directory (`.`) itself, just the directories found under it. Change `**/*` to `{.,**/*}` to also consider `.`).

Answer (score 0):

With the `bash` shell, you can test whether the current directory contains any names ending in `.bam`, and print a message if it doesn't, like so:

```bash
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
set -- ./*.bam
[ "$#" = 0 ] && echo 'nothing found'
```

The `dotglob` shell option allows `*` to match hidden names, and the `nullglob` shell option removes the pattern if it does not match anything (rather than leaving the pattern unchanged).

With `set` we can expand the pattern and set the list of positional parameters to the matching names.  If `$#`, the length of the list of positional parameters, is zero, then there were no names matching the pattern.

We can use `find` to apply this piece of code to the current directories and to all the directories beneath the current directory:

```bash
find . -type d -exec bash -O dotglob -O nullglob -c '
    for d do
        set -- "$d"/*.bam
        [ "$#" = 0 ] && printf "%s\n" "$d"
    done' bash {} +
```

This finds all directories recursively, starting at `.`, and feeds them in batches to the given in-line `bash` script.  The script iterates over the given directory paths and applies the `set` command and the test in each in turn, printing the pathnames of the directories that yielded no matching names.

---

The shell also has a `failglob` shell option that generates a failure when a pattern does not match anything.  We can use this to make the code a tiny (tiny!) bit shorter but arguably also more unreadable:

```bash
find . -type d -exec bash -O dotglob -O failglob -c '
    for d do
        (set -- "$d"/*.bam) 2>/dev/null || printf "%s\n" "$d"
    done' bash {} +
```

Comment: *"also more unreadable"* and less efficient as it forks an extra process per directory. Two other notable differences compared to `zsh`'s `*(ND.Y1)`: it doesn't restrict the globs to files of type *regular* and it does expand to all the matching files and sorts them (whilst with `Y1`, zsh stops at the first match).

Comment: Also beware of that bash misdesign: `failglob` (which you would want on by default if it was less broken) has precedence over `nullglob` (which you do occasionally want temporarily like here), so when using `shopt -s nullglob`, you also need `shopt -u failglob` unless you know for sure `failglob` was not previously enabled (and that generally in a subshell as bash still don't support scoping for its set of options toggled with shopt -s/u)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @waltinator's `comm` utility idea, `grep` can be useful in removing a set of strings from its standard input.

```
$ find mypath/ -type d | 
    grep -Fvxf <(find mypath/ -name \*.bam -type f -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq)
```

To explain the syntax, the left side of the pipe creates a list of all the directories under `mypath/`.  On the right side, notice the parentheses.  Like in math, that part is done first.  `find` locates all `*.bam` files under `mypath/` but prints only the directory path of each one.  That output is then `sort`ed (possibly unnecessary but doesn't hurt except for what little time it may take), and `uniq`ed so that each directory name appears only once.  The `uniq`ing is a courtesy to `grep`, to prevent it from searching multiple times for the same directory name.  Once `grep` has the list of directories to remove, it removes each directory resulting from the parenthesized command substitution (the list of `*.bam` file locations) from its input stream (the master list of all directories).  The remaining output is the set of directories that do not contain a `*.bam` file.

Answer (score -1):

As said by @waltinator in the comments, you can use the find command:

```bash
find /your/path -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}" | egrep -i -q "^.*\.bam$"' ';' -print
```

The explanation can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/196966).

**Sample output**:

```bash
$ find /usr/libexec -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -i -q "^.*\.so$"' ';' -print
/usr/libexec
/usr/libexec/emacs
/usr/libexec/emacs/29.1
/usr/libexec/emacs/29.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
/usr/libexec/man-db
/usr/libexec/gcc
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/plugin
/usr/libexec/git-core
/usr/libexec/git-core/mergetools
/usr/libexec/podman
/usr/libexec/nullmailer
```